# Is it possibile to create a master detail grid with cell render based on a network call?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I created a static master detail grid with some data inside and it works fine, now I would like to populate my "node child detail" getting data from a network call, is it possible? 
My code is very similar to [this](https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid-react-example/tree/master/src/masterDetailExample/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was searching in the wrong direction. The solution is to use the [lazy loading of groups](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-enterprise-model/?framework=react#gsc.tab=0)